# Issues understanding nested PHP ternary operator ? echo $a ? 'a' : $b ? 'b' : 'c';

Tags: php, ternary-operator

```
$a = true;
$b = false;
echo $a ? 'a' : ($b ? 'b' : 'c');
output a
```

I understand this .
If have read and search on internet about : nested PHP ternary operator
But still I don't understand why this has the following output ?

```
    $a = true;
    $b = false;
    echo $a ? 'a' : $b ? 'b' : 'c';

    output b
```

why ?
Can someone translate this expression in classical if - else ?
Thanks

Comment: Does `echo ($a ? 'a' : $b) ? 'b' : 'c'` help?

Comment: @ScottHunter now makes sense and I understand . Thanks

Answer (score 2):

```php
echo $a ? 'a' : ($b ? 'b' : 'c');
```

This code says: If $a is true, output 'a', else, output the result from the following:
   If b is true, output 'b', else output 'c'

So in that example, it would output 'a'.

```php
echo $a ? 'a' : $b ? 'b' : 'c';
```

This example says: If ($a ? 'a' : $b) is true, output 'b' else 'c'. If we look at what ($a ? 'a' : $b) evaluates to, it says: If $a is true, output 'a', else output 'b'.

If you look at PHP's [type comparison table](https://www.php.net/manual/en/types.comparisons.php), you can see that strings evaluate to true, unless they are empty or '0'. So because of this, the output of ($a ? 'a' : $b) - 'a', evaluates to true. Thus, it outputs 'b'.

Comment: Thanks.You mention the same explanation as  @ScottHunter had said above  echo ($a ? 'a' : $b) ? 'b' : 'c' . I don't understand this part "if you look at PHP's type comparison table,  '" , I don't understand how you can use the table that you have mention ?

Comment: @leonidaa If you click on my link, you can see the table of comparisons. If you find $x = "" in the table, you can see that under boolean, it evaluates to false, but if you find $x = "1", you can see it evaluates to true.